# PHP how to redirect url path to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I currently have a website with URLs with this pattern

```
https://website.com/?p=something
```

where p is the requested page (like /?p=login)

for SEO reasons i want the URL to look like this

```
https://website.com/login/
```

Of course I could do a redirect like this

```
Redirect 301 /login/ https://website.com/?p=login
```

But it would change the URL displayed in the users browser back to the URL with parameters in it.

My question is, how can I have an URL like this `https://website.com/login/` but in PHP inside the index.php I could access the requestet page or "path" like before like `$page = $_GET['p'];`. In other words I want to redirect the URL `https://website.com/login/` to `https://website.com/?p=login` but having the URL still displayed as `https://website.com/login/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use .htaccess file to point all requests to the server to one file for example index.php

```
# Rewrite Engine ON
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect everything to one file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

After that you can code a router to handle URI components.

For example someone call sitename/login

You detect /login and open the required page

Comment: is it possible to make an exception to that rule? eg. for /sidemap.xml ?

Comment: I tried to add the following condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^sitemap.xml` but it's still being redirected...

Comment: This above is working only for paths without extensions, so no need to change it sitename/sitemap.xml will work aswell as sitemap/script.php.